# Can we do something about this self-promoting, spamming user?

Tags: discussion, users, user-accounts

This user obviously just promotes whatever company they work for:

https://academia.stackexchange.com/users/7262/kimberly-fujioka

Comment: You can edit the posts where you think there is excessive self-promotion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking through their posts (including the deleted one), this user doesn't seem to be self-promoting beyond including a sig in her answers. Considering that she posted all her answers within two hours of each other and the edits to remove her sig were (for the most part) made towards the end of her posting, I'd give her another shot before taking excessive action. To quote some famous dead person,

> Never attribute to malice that which is adequately explained by stupidity.

In this case, we'd substitute "unfamiliar with the social norms in our community" for "stupidity", but the concept still applies.

If this behavior continues please flag the relevant posts and we'll take further action.

Comment: In fact from the description of her company in her profile, the answers she has provided don't even seem obviously linked.

Comment: @DanielE.Shub - I agree, but the community has done the "modding" quite well, downvoting her posts and editing out her sig. At this point, I don't think any further action is warranted. If the behavior continues we can consider next steps.

Comment: @LeonMeier - Considering that this post was from 2013 and that this user has been inactive since just around that date, I'd say it's pretty moot at this point.